Using an aggregate function and still getting 'not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause' error
I'm trying to retrieve the last invoice by location but end up getting the following error: 'invoice_date is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'
I've tried
SELECT item_id
 ,location_name
 ,SUM(invoice_date) OVER(PARTITION BY location_name) AS LastInvoiceDate
FROM items_report AS InactiveItems
GROUP BY item_id, location_name
ORDER BY item_id

But still receive the error

If you want to get the last invoice by location you don't use the sum aggregate function, you should use max instead like this:
SELECT item_id, location_name, MAX(invoice_date) AS LastInvoiceDate
FROM items_report AS InactiveItems
GROUP BY item_id, location_name
ORDER BY item_id


If this is for MS SQL Server, you just need to use MAX()
SELECT item_id
 ,location_name
 ,MAX(invoice_date) AS LastInvoiceDate
FROM items_report AS InactiveItems
GROUP BY item_id, location_name
ORDER BY item_id

